# How to configure EF database first for production environment?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

So we have developed an MVC application with EF database first and are trying to deploy the solution to Production environment. however the database server is on a different server and hence we would have to provide a conenction string pointing to the DB server. We tried couple of methods but weren't successful.

Whats the approach for deployments for EF DB first?

Comment: Please add the methods you've tried.

Comment: Just change your connectionstring in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?

```
Configuration connectionConfiguration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        connectionConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString = txtConnectionString.Text;
connectionConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

It will rewrite your web.config with new values

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to a production environment, an application is typically compiled in `Release` mode. In this mode you can use `Web.Release.config` to specify the variables that should be different in production.

Say your connection string in `Web.config` is

```
<add name="MyContext"
     connectionString="DevConnectionString" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can add this in `Web.Release.config`:

```
<add name="MyContext"
     connectionString="ProdConnectionString" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
     xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

When deploying to production the connection string will automatically change to "ProdConnectionString".

For more information on Web.config transforms see [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)